# Listview выбор элементов

Tags: android

У меня есть список детей в *listview extended by BaseAdapter*.

Необходимо по нажатию на элемент из списка менять ему *Layout*.

Я сделал то, что нужно, через кейсы и состояния *Вьюшки*, но работает только для одного элемента. Т.е., когда выбираю любой элемент из списка, он меняет свой *layout* со всеми вытекающими. Но когда я выбираю второй элемент, первый переходит в начальное состояния. А мне надо, чтобы список был независимый, чтобы я мог по нажатию выбирать столько детей, сколько мне надо.

Как это реализовать?

Вот код *CustomerAdapter*:
`

```
public class ChildrensStateAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ChildrensState> arrayList;
    int select = -1;
    private static final int IS_START_ANSWER = 0;
    private static final int IS_END_ANSWER = 1;
    public boolean isStarted  = false;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater cInflater;

public ChildrensStateAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChildrensState> arrayList){
    this.cInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;

}

public void setSelect(int select){
    this.select = select;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(select == position && isStarted == true){

        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (arrayList == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public ChildrensState getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    holder= new ViewHolder();
    int type = getItemViewType(position);


    ChildrensState item = (ChildrensState) getItem(position);



    if(convertView==null)
    {
        switch (type) {
            case IS_END_ANSWER:
                convertView=cInflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_children_adapter_lesson, parent,false);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childrens_textView_lessons);
                holder.averageMark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_averagemark_textView);
                holder.absenceChildrens = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_absencechildrens_checkBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;
            case IS_START_ANSWER:
                convertView=cInflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_children_adapter_answer, parent,false);
                holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.childrens_textView_answer);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;
        }

    }
    else {
        holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    switch (type){
        case IS_END_ANSWER:
            holder.name.setText(" " + item.listNumb + ". " + item.name);
            holder.averageMark.setText(String.valueOf(8.8));
            holder.absenceChildrens.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
            holder.absenceChildrens.setTag(position);
            holder.absenceChildrens.setChecked(item.absenceChildrens);
            holder.absenceChildrens.getTag(position);

            break;
        case IS_START_ANSWER:
            holder.name.setText(" " + item.listNumb + ". " + item.name);
            break;
    }


    return convertView;

}

ChildrensState getChildrensState(int position){
    return ((ChildrensState)getItem(position));
}

ArrayList<ChildrensState> getAbsence(){
    ArrayList<ChildrensState> absence = new ArrayList<ChildrensState>();
    for(ChildrensState c : arrayList){
        if(c.absenceChildrens)
            absence.add(c);
    }
    return absence;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
        getChildrensState((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).absenceChildrens = isChecked;
    }
};


public class ViewHolder{
    public TextView name;
    public CheckBox absenceChildrens;
    public TextView averageMark;
}

}
```

И в Main Activity:

```
ChildrensState childrenState = new ChildrensState();
childrensStateArray = childrenState.getChildrenState(response);
childrensStateAdapter = new ChildrensStateAdapter(getApplicationContext(),childrensStateArray);
    lvChildrensState = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.childrenlist);
    lvChildrensState.setAdapter(childrensStateAdapter);
    lvChildrensState.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    lvChildrensState.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            childrensStateAdapter.isStarted = true;
            mSelectedItem = position;
            childrensStateAdapter.setSelect(mSelectedItem);
            childrensStateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LongClick" + mSelectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну это, короче, не проблема))
Вы в своём списке у айтемов состояние то не сохраняете.(судя по коду).
Не знаю что у вас в классе **ChildrensState**, но добавьте туда следующее:

```
 class ChildrensState {
    private static final int IS_START_ANSWER = 0;
    private static final int IS_END_ANSWER = 1;

    private int state;

    public void setState(int state) {
       this.state = state;
    }

    public int getState() {
       return state;
    }

 }
```

перепишите

```
 public void setSelect(int select){
   this.select = select;
 }
```

на

```
 public void setSelect(int selectState, int position){
   getItem(position).setType(selectState);
 }
```

в методе **onItemClick** передавайте константу:

```
 childrensStateAdapter.setSelect(ChildrensState.IS_START_ANSWER, position);
```

и наконец в методе getView() исправьте:

```
 int type = getItem(position).getType;
```

и вы увидите конец пути!

P.S. писал прямо здесь возможны мелкие недочёты - тут вы уж сами